Finding definition in source file with a single call
Emacs configuration:

eglot

language-server: clangd


xref-find-definitions on M-.
ff-find-other-file on C-x p o
xref-go-back on M-,

Situation:
I'm currently in a source file (let's say foo_temp.c). There is a fuction call to foo_hmi_showTemp(...). I place the point on the call and press M-.
Now emacs jumps to foo_hmi.h. As I know that this is a function that is compiled by me and no library I also have access to foo_hmi.c.
In 99.9% of my usecases I want to jump to the definition in foo_hmi.c.
If foo_hmi.c has no buffer associated with it and I now press M-. in foo_hmi.h nothing happens.
If I now press C-x p o emacs will visit foo_hmi.c (at line 1).
If I now press M-, I am back in foo_hmi.h.
Now pressing M-. will result in visiting not only foo_hmi.c but also the function definition.

This means my current routine is:

M-.
C-x p o
M-,
M-.

Just to get to the definition of the function if the file I want to visit is not already opened in a buffer.
This is rather cumbersum compared to my desired situation where M-. is enough.
Has anyone a suggestion how set this up "correctly" or improve the behavior (shorten the amount of necessary steps)?

Vim-ness notwithstanding, https://neovim.discourse.group/t/clangd-lsp-jump-to-definition-takes-me-to-h-file/2153 looks relevant (which I found via a search based on the assumption that this must be a clang configuration issue).  Maybe https://neovim.discourse.group/t/switch-to-h-cpp-via-lsp/813 as well.  That's all I have (I don't write C code or use LSP).

You are absolutly right. I tried your first link using the compile_commands.json instead of compile_flags.txt solved the root problem.

Great!  If you write up the specifics in an Answer, you can then Accept that.

Sorry, I need to rewind my acception.
Sometimes it works, sometimes not. So far it's not clear when and why.
